# creating a reservation program facing a Name error

Tags: python, nameerror

I was making a program to create a reservation and I keep getting a NameError. I believe it is out of scope but I am not completely sure how to fix it. Tried assigning it to global but it didn't work either. I was wondering if anyone had a solution to this? Thank you.

```
    def get_seating_chart( ):
    global seating_chart
    seating_chart =   [['O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O'],
                                    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                                    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'],
                                    ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                                    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'],
                                    ['O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                                    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                                    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                                    ['O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O'],
                                    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X']]
    return seating_chart

def reserve_seat(row, seat, seating_chart):
    row = 0
    seat = 0
    if seating_chart[row][seat] == 'X':
        print("Sorry, Seat taken!")
        return False
    else:
        seating_chart[row][seat] = "X"
        print(seating_chart)
        return True
    if (choice == 2):
            print("Make a Reservation")
            print("--------------------")
            #file = open("reservation.txt", "r")
            #first = input("Enter Passenger First Name:")
            #last = input("Enter Passenger Last Name:")
            print(("Printing the Seating Chart..."))
            print(get_seating_chart( ))
            int(input("Which row would you like to sit in?"))
            int(input("Which seat would you like to sit in?"))
            print(reserve_seat(row, seat, seating_chart)(seating_chart))
            if success:
                print("YaY! seat reserved!" )
            #generate confirmation code
            #write reservation (name, row, seat, code) to reservations.txt file
            else:
                print("Sorry, try again.")
    def main( ):
    seating_chart = get_seating_chart( )
    success = reserve_seat(row-1, seat-1, seating_chart)
    
main( )
```

error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/tylerolznoi/Desktop/Python
> Projects/FinalProject/final_project_files/res_system_[tjo5fh].py",
> line 86, in 
> print(reserve_seat(row, seat, seating_chart)(seating_chart)) NameError: name 'row' is not defined

Comment: Your indentation is confusing, you may want to double check it. Assuming `main()` is not actually defined inside of `reserve_seat()`, then you're trying to pass in `row` and `seat`, but you haven't defined them at the point you invoke the function in `main`.

Comment: What is your `reserve_seat` function supposed to do?  Is it supposed to reserve a seat at the `row, seat` you pass to it, or is it supposed to ask the user for the row and seat and try to reserve that?  The error is coming from the fact that you're trying to pass `row` and `seat` in before anything has defined them.

Comment: you send in main the variables `row` and `seat` to `reseerve_seat` although they are not known there

Comment: It looks almost like this might have been a working program at one point and somebody just randomly reordered parts of it.  Some of the code in `reserve_seat` looks like it should actually be in `main`.

Comment: It asks the user what row and seat they would like to reserve their seat to from the seating chart. When they choose what seat and row, the seating chart list changes to an "X" to show the seat is taken.

Comment: in main function define row and seat or set a default value for them in the reserve_seat function

Comment: you haven't take user input for row and seat, you need to add that part

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Fix your indentation and remove code that's superfluous to the problem.
The reason for the undefined symbol is obvious, as you already spotted.
How to fix it depends on your project design.  Your `main` calls for the seating chart, and then expects `row` and `col` to be magically defined.  The code that interacts with the user is inside `reserve_seat`, which you haven't yet called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of the code (with some pretty-printing logic added).  You don't need `global`s, you just need things to happen in the right order, and for each function to do the thing it says it does.

```
def make_seating_chart():
    return[
        ['O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'],
        ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'],
        ['O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X']
    ]

def print_seating_chart(seating_chart):
    print("\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in seating_chart))

def reserve_seat(row, seat, seating_chart):
    if seating_chart[row][seat] == 'X':
        return False
    else:
        seating_chart[row][seat] = "X"
        return True

def main():
    seating_chart = make_seating_chart()

    print("Make a Reservation")
    print("--------------------")
    # file = open("reservation.txt", "r")
    # first = input("Enter Passenger First Name:")
    # last = input("Enter Passenger Last Name:")
    print("Printing the Seating Chart...")
    print_seating_chart(seating_chart)
    row = int(input("Which row would you like to sit in?"))
    seat = int(input("Which seat would you like to sit in?"))

    success = reserve_seat(row, seat, seating_chart)

    if success:
        print("YaY! seat reserved!")
        print_seating_chart(seating_chart)
        # generate confirmation code
        # write reservation (name, row, seat, code) to reservations.txt file
    else:
        print("Sorry, Seat taken!")

main()
```

The main problem was that you had code inside `reserve_seat` that really should happen before `reserve_seat` is called -- namely, the part that figures out what seat to reserve!  I moved that code into `main()` and fixed it so that `reserve_seat` **only** reserves the seat -- it doesn't print anything, it doesn't prompt the user for input, it just tries to reserve the seat that you ask for and returns whether it was successful.

The `main` function now handles the task of figuring out what `row` and `seat` are (by prompting the user -- you'd written this part of the code but it was in the wrong place and you weren't actually using the values that you prompted for) so that it can use them to call `reserve_seat`.  It also handles the step of printing what the result was.

I also changed `get_seating_chart` to `make_seating_chart` since it's a function that creates the chart (rather than getting an existing one) -- if you call it more than once and it overwrites a global variable with its result, it'll re-make the chart (erasing any changes you've made), so it's good to be clear on the difference!  Note that the updated `main()` function calls `make_seating_chart()` exactly once and then reuses the same `seating_chart` from that point forward.